# Not able to import mule jar in my local AnyPoint studio which is being built and downloaded from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I am able to build and deploy **Mulesoft API** on a remote **MuleSoft-CloudHub** through Jenkins.

But when I download the same **jar** from **Jenkins** to my local machine and when I try to import the **jar** to my local **AnyPoint** studio, it is not happening and throwing the below error.

Any suggestions on this..??

[image]

Comment: Besides not including the sources as the person below answered, this also happens when there is no mule-project.xml (3.x) or mule-artificact.json (4.x) file included with your source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project is probably being built without including sources. That resulting jar can be deployed but not imported into studio. To include the sources set the maven property  -DattachMuleSources as explained in the documentation page https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.1/mmp-concept#import-your-generated-jar-to-anypoint-studio